# How to configuring prettier for graphql files?

Tags: prettier

I have Prettier installed as a plugin in VS Code, in addition I also installed it as an NPM package but it does not format the file (following) correctly. there should be commas between each line.

I tried the Plugin and  NPM package, together and separately but it didn't make a difference.

*schema.gql*

```
type Mutation {
  addBook(
    title: String
    subtitle: String
    author: String
    editor: String
    thumbnail: String
    category: String
    ...
  ): Book
}
```

Comment: It's working correctly,  (Sort of...) Commas aren't strictly required, but I'd love to know how to configure Prettier to include them.